# Securing Database Credential in a Field deployed Raspberry Pi

Tags: password-management

A raspberry pi is deployed in a public area.  I am not so concerned about the physical theft of the raspberry pi: I am concerned that the device is stolen, the SD card will be read and the AWS database credentials (username / password in python script) will be 'in the wild'.

Are there any effective security practices that can mitigate this risk?

UPDATE: Every reasonable attempt will be made to physically secure the device (locked in a box), however, the chances of theft is not zero.

Comment: If you are not concerned about the physical threat than why are you concerned about something physical being stolen (SD card)?

Comment: I think the OP means they’re not concerned about the dollar value of the lost raspberry pi.

Comment: Exactly.  The information (credentials) is the subject of concern

Comment: @gatorback - Will the device be permanently powered? If so just load the credentials into memory at app start (i.e. from a removable USB drive or similar). Then to steal them an attacker would have to steal the pi, gain access and take a memory dump of the process all without cutting the power. I'd imagine you're not worried about targeted attacks here?

Comment: Great question and idea!  Well, the pi will be powered and might have limited battery backup (UPS).  I am not sure what is meant by a targeted attack.  From a network standpoint it will reside on a private LAN behind a firewall.   Maybe reframe your response as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

First things first ... **physical access is root access**.  If someone can physically touch your device, it is no longer your device.

With that out of the way, what can you do to limit the threat?

- Lock down access to the AWS to the specific IP (possibly even [port security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_filtering) if possible) ... this way even if someone steals the creds out of the python script they can't do anything without using the same connection it was originally on.
- Lock down the DB User to the min Read/Write access required by the script so that if someone gains access they cant dump the entire database and/or drop tables. (see also [Database Trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger))
- Write a remote API wrapper around the Database access (see also [redis pub/sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub)) so that the RPi can only do commands allowed by the API, and remotely log all API request good & bad.
- Remotely deploy code to memory only.  If you setup a bootstrap to pull code to a ram drive (see also [loop0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device)), run it, and delete the local copy ... it should only be accessible if the thief can steal it while maintaining power.

Again, you can't fully protect your AWS but you can harden it and buy yourself time to invalidate the User or API key associated with the RPi.  Just make sure you regularly check logs for nefarious activity.

Comment: Putting an API around the data opens up a lot of possibilities for custom rules, like short-lived access token with a refresh token, limiting access per device, rate-limiting, pairing tokens with the IP address, limiting data to reasonable values, etc.

Comment: Remote code deployment seems like a clever option with other good benefits.  Any pointers to rPi remote code deployment is appreciated.  Wondering if disk encryption is possible / effective?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed that Physical access is bad -- but there are some things you can do, that will at least delay the attacker long enough for you to notice the PI is missing, and change credentials on the DB.

First off, goes without saying, you need to secure the Pi physically, and ensure you have systems in place to notice it missing as soon as possible. Daily physical inspection -- and perhaps maybe a remote script to check if the Pi is still connected to the network that runs every 20-30 minutes. If the Pi is disconnected from the network, the script alerts you, and you now can act on it.

Try ensuring there's full disk encryption on the Pi. I'm not an expert in Raspbian or whatever OS you're running, but a properly implemented Disk Encryption, will at least slow down the attacker -- or at most stop them dead in their tracks.

Depending on your DB, try using AWS secrets manager. In this setup, all you have on the Pi is an AWS API key setup for non-root IAM USER that has very limited permissions. The API call returns the database credentials for you to use. The magic is that, you can not only disable the API Key with a click/command, you can also rotate the database secrets without touching your application. This gives you much easier flexibility to prevent access once the Pi is discovered missing.

It's all about defence-in-depth. The attacker has to physically remove the SD card on your Pi (or steal the Pi entirely), bypass the FDE, and then bypass the OS password, and then all the have the key to the database-- which hopefully you've already disabled by then.

Secrets manager cost $0.50/secret per month, and shouldn't be too hard to implement via [Boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.get_secret_value) (defauly Python SDK for AWS). If you're running something like DynamoDB, you probably can live without it, by simply disabling the IAM user (or their API key) that has access to the DB.

Comment: Excellent approach and innovative layers (AWS Secrets).  Database=MySQL RDBMS.